# PHP: Group items by day to display results

Tags: php, grouping

Sorry if this is a n00b question as I'm more of a UX designer, not a developer. I posted this in the WordPress forums and was directed here, so here it goes...

I'm trying to query a custom post type in Wordpress and return results grouped by a custom meta date. I have the loop and code working to display all posts that I want, but am having issues trying to group them by the custom meta date.

I'd like for the query to find all dates in the meta_value, display them as an h3, then create a ul for the posts with each as an li.

The custom meta date is saved as mm/dd/yy HH:MM. I did it this way since there is an associated start date field i needed anyway and it lets me use WordPress's orderby. I simply format the output as I desire when needed.

I can't seem to wrap my head around 1) where to put the h3 and ul; and 2) grouping the items by date. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$all_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'agenda',
    'category' => the_title,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'cpt_agenda-event-date',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$all_agenda_posts = get_posts( $all_args );                         
foreach( $all_agenda_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
$metas = get_post_meta( get_the_ID( ), 'cpt_agenda-event-date', false );

// If you want to show values
foreach ( $metas as $meta ) {
    $meta;
    $formatted = date("l, F j", strtotime($meta));
    echo '<h3>' . $formatted . '</h3>';
}
?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I also have images posted at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42846/group-posts-by-custom-meta-field-date that show the current output and the desired output. Please ignore the time fields and style as the CSS needs to be applied once working correctly.

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE: I got this working and the code is below in case it helps someone else. I needed to use tax_query...**

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem may be your use of the $post var.  You're calling the global $post var and then using the same var name in your foreach:

```
foreach( $all_agenda_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
```

These are in conflict, try changing to

```
foreach( $all_agenda_posts as $aa_post ) : setup_postdata($aa_post);
```

Another possible problem is in  your arg array.
You have:

```
'category' => the_title,
```

I think this should be

```
'category' => the_title(),
```

Lastly, get_the_ID() returns the id of the current/global $post which you have over-ridden due to the first error.  Assuming you rename the $post in the foreach to $aa_post, change

```
$metas = get_post_meta( get_the_ID( ), 'cpt_agenda-event-date', false );
```

to

```
$metas = get_post_meta( $aa_post->ID, 'cpt_agenda-event-date', false );
```

This should get you a little closer.

Comment: Hi Brian. First, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, once I change the foreach the loop gives me a single post from a separate category and post type. I'm not quite sure why actually.

I believe you're correct about the_title () and I've changed it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Using tax_query helped me. I just copied/paste the code from the working example so there are a few things added.

```
<?php
global $post;

$term = get_term_by('name', $event_name, 'agenda_category');


$all_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'agenda',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'cpt_agenda-event-date',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'agenda_category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $term->term_id
        )
    )
);

$all_agenda_posts = new WP_Query($all_args);
$prev_start_date    =   "";

while ( $all_agenda_posts->have_posts() ) : $all_agenda_posts->the_post();
    $agenda_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID( ), 'cpt_agenda-event-date', true);
    $agenda_end_time = get_post_meta( get_the_ID( ), 'cpt_agenda-end-time', true);

    if($prev_start_date!=date("l, F dS", strtotime($agenda_date))) {
        echo    "<h3>".date("l, F dS", strtotime($agenda_date))."</h3>";
        $prev_start_date    =   date("l, F dS", strtotime($agenda_date));   
    }
 ?>
<div class="schedule">
    <div class="stime"><?php echo date("h:i a", strtotime($agenda_date)); ?>
<?php if ($agenda_end_time){
    echo ' to ';
    echo date("h:i a", strtotime($agenda_end_time));
} else {
    echo '';
}
?>
    </div>
    <div class="stitle">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;

if ( $agenda_disclaimer ) { ?>
    <p class="change">~ <?php echo $agenda_disclaimer; ?> ~</p>
<?php }
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```